# Unable to create AWS key pair using console

Tags: amazon-web-services, key-pair

I tried to create new AWS key pairs and the option to create disappeared
Does anyone know why?

[image: i]

Comment: I wonder whether it is related to the AMI you selected? Are you launching a normal AMI from the "Quick Start" page, or is it an AMI from the AWS Marketplace or somewhere different?

Comment: @John Rotenstein I tried both - Quick start of Linux machine & Custom AMI from different browsers and different accounts..

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth checking the IAM permissions associated with the User who is trying to create the key pair. Contact the Administrator (presumably you?) and investigate. I would suggest creating a Group with Permissions and adding them to that.

Comment: I checked it with more than one account, I don't think this is the issue...

Comment: That is strange. You could look at logging a Support Ticket (Console > Top right). Or else, if you are familiar with the AWS CLI, you could look at creating a KP there? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-key-pair.html

Answer (score 0):

I performed an experiment and added a`Deny` policy to my IAM User that prevented me from being able to create a keypair.

I then tried to launch an instance and the option to create a keypair (in the dialog box you show above) **was still available**. So, the display does not vary according to permissions.

Therefore, something else is causing your situation. I would recommend trying it in a different browser. Also, check the underlying HTML to see whether the option is coded on the web page. *Something* is causing it to disappear.